# SQL Server dbo.sysdiagrams is a user table or system table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

When use Database Diagrams in a simple database, SQL Server create a dbo.sysdiagrams table in the `Table\Systam Tables` node (in Microsoft management studio\object explorer). But sysdiagrams table marked as user table in SQL Server. you can get user table by below query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.tables t
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(t.object_id,'IsUserTable') = 1
```

[image]

I don't know that sysdiagram table is a system table or is a user table.

Exists `microsoft_database_tools_support` with value `1` In the extended property of sysdiagram, that determine this table created automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

System tables are used internally by the SQL Server, they are the same in every user database.

sysdiagrams is not a system table from the server point of view.

But SQL Server Management Studio creates it to store the diagram data, so it also categorizes it as a system table.

You can exclude such kinda system tables using the extended attribute you mentionned.

Comment: I'm curious about this table. Is not marked as is_ms_shipped on either `sys.objects` or `sys.tables`. And any other flag that points towards been a system table are also zero. So how can this be checked?

Comment: @atesio I just copied all the tables other than system tables from one db to another.  Is it mandatory that I also copy dbo.sysdiagrams to the new db?

Comment: copying dbo.sysdiagrams is not mandatory, this table stored the diagram data (designed within SQL Server Management Studio, no other use than documentation of your model). If you want the diagrams transferred you can copy the contents of this table, diagrams will then be viewable on the target database.

Answer (score 19):

Management Studio utilizes the following in its determination of "System Objects" where "tbl" is sys.tables:

```
CAST(
 case 
    when tbl.is_ms_shipped = 1 then 1
    when (
        select 
            major_id 
        from 
            sys.extended_properties 
        where 
            major_id = tbl.object_id and 
            minor_id = 0 and 
            class = 1 and 
            name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support') 
        is not null then 1
    else 0
end          
             AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject]
```

Comment: I need to know how Management Studio was moving what seemed by all other accounts a user table into the system tables branch of the tree. This answered my questions and allowed me to avoid hard coding table names in my scripts.

Comment: I just checked upon 'sys.objects' on a SQL Server 2014