# SQL Server sysdiagrams table not showing consistently in the same location

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

While using [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) v17.7, I noticed that sometimes the `dbo.sysdiagrams` table (the table that is automatically generated when you enable the database diagrams functionality) is shown under the `System Tables` folder while other times it is shown under the regular `Tables` directory.

Specifically (as far as I can tell so far), when exploring a database hosted in Azure I see the `dbo.sysdiagrams` under the `Tables` directory. However, if I explore a local database (hosted on my computer), I see the `dbo.sysdiagrams` under the `System Tables` directory.

Although not a biggie, I am curios to find out if there is a way to make sure that the `dbo.sysdiagrams` is always shown under the `System Tables` folder since I would prefer it to be out of the way.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: [SQL Server dbo.sysdiagrams is a user table or system table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270328/sql-server-dbo-sysdiagrams-is-a-user-table-or-system-table)

Comment: Why you need to know where is located?

Comment: @ Alberto Morillo: I don't understand your reply. I already know where the table is located. Not sure what you mean.